# YEAR() and MONTH() in Doctrine2 with Symfony 2.4

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.4

I've just installed [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) to use SQL functions MONTH() and YEAR() but I keep getting this error:

**Attempted to load class "Month" from namespace "DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql" in /var/www/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 3389. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?**

In my controller I have this:

```
$dql = "SELECT x FROM PFCFisiogestBundle:FacturaEmitida x WHERE MONTH(x.fecha) BETWEEN '".$mes_inicio."' AND '".$mes_fin."' 
                AND YEAR(x.fecha) = '".$ano."' ORDER BY x.numero DESC";
$queryDefault = $em->createQuery($dql);
```

And in config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
            string_functions:
                MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

What am I missing? :-(

Comment: Verify you have a vendor/berberlei/DoctrineExtension directory.  The stof bundle that you referenced does not load these particular extensions.  You might need to add: "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "*" to your composer.json file.

Answer (score 2):

That bundle is a sf2 wrapper for *behavioural Doctrine extensions*, which is a different case than yours

Try this [orocrm/doctrine-extensions](https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions) .. it supports MySQL and Postgres too ... should support other DBMS in future